# some mobile can't be download pdf from url(POST ) in android

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivU1a.png)File downloading from stream(url  respunce)i am tried to no mobile.but not working some mobiles,file was created not writing.
i am changing  byte[4096], byte[1024]...,same error occur
please give any one suggestion to me

```
public void saveToDisk(ResponseBody body, String pdfFileName, String module_type, String test_name) {
    try {
        File sdcard_destinationFile;
        if (module_type.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")) {

            sdcard_destinationFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/download/" + pdfFileName + "_" + test_name + ".pdf");
        } else {
            sdcard_destinationFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/download/" + pdfFileName + ".pdf");
        }


        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;

        try {
            Log.e("file",body+"");
            is = body.byteStream();
            os = new FileOutputStream(sdcard_destinationFile);
            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            int count;
            int progress = 0;
            while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
                os.write(data, 0, count);
                progress += count;
                Log.d(TAG, "Progress: " + progress + "/" + body.contentLength() + " >>>> " + (float) progress / body.contentLength());
            }
            Log.d("aaaaa", "Progress: " + progress + "/" + body.contentLength() + " >>>> " + (float) progress / body.contentLength());
            os.flush();
            Log.e("isis",is +"");
            Log.e("isis",os +"");
            if (is != null) is.close();
            if (os != null) os.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "File saved successfully!");
         showPdf(pdfFileName, module_type, test_name);
           return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to save the file!");
            return;
        } finally {

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to save the file!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: please put stack trace

Comment: I can't find anything wrong in this code. You need to add version specific code for handling multiple devices Try using a multi-device compatible file downloader. You can try using TestTube library available on GitHub

Comment: i attached image you colud check now and same file working mobile memory allocation is 30 KB but hear same file only 57 B

Comment: I rather use  [`DownloadManger`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) for downloading files easy to use and no headache of handling byte flow .

Comment: thank you ADM
i used DownloadManger i got some error